# Adding with increment int

Tags: c#, unique, increment

I have a problem with my unique textbox id's.
My code is creating a div with 4 textboxes for each ship in my database.
Each created textbox must have an unique ID.
I do this with increment int (int i = 0 and i++) but can't seem to get it working. Here is my code!

```
while (oReader.Read());
{
    int i = 0;
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
    this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
    List<TextBox> tb_names = new List<TextBox>();
    TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();

    //TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["SchipNaam"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Scheepspnaam: <input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name1 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["RederijNr"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> RederijNr:<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name2 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["Lengte"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Lengte  :<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name3 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["Laadvermogen"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Laadvermogen:<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);
    i++;
}
```

My output is always CreateT_0_1. What am I doing wrong? I thought it worked before but can't seem to find the issue.

I hope that you guys see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're resetting `i` for every iteration of your `while` loop, you then always suffix `_1`?

Comment: The extra semi-colon at the end of the first line probably isn't helping, either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create i with value 0 at the beginning of each while loop. Initialise the integer before the loop and then update it within the loop, otherwise it will reset to 0 on each iteration.

You are adding 3 text boxes within the while loop, but you only increment i at the end of the while loop. You will need to change your suffix as this is always _1 or use i++ between each text box to make the identifier unique.

As Jon Skeet mentioned in a comment above, the semicolon on the line of the while initiation should not be needed.

```
int i = 0;
while (oReader.Read())
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
    this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
    List<TextBox> tb_names = new List<TextBox>();
    TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();

    //TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString();
    tb_name.Text = oReader["SchipNaam"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Scheepspnaam: <input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name1 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["RederijNr"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> RederijNr:<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name2 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_2";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["Lengte"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Lengte  :<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);

    //TextBox tb_name3 = new TextBox();
    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_3";
    tb_name.Text = oReader["Laadvermogen"].ToString();
    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
    ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> Laadvermogen:<input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
    tb_names.Add(tb_name);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, this helped me a a lot! It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have given 1 as fixed string in the line 
tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i.ToString() + "_1"; so it was not working 
try the below code

```
while (oReader.Read());

            {
                int i = 0;
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
                new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
                this.Controls.Add(createDiv);
                List<TextBox> tb_names = new List<TextBox>();
                TextBox tb_name = new TextBox();


                 var lstText=new List<string>
                    {
                    "Scheepspnaam",
                    "RederijNr",
                    "Lengte",
                    "Laadvermogen"
                };

                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    tb_name.ID = "CreateT_" + i + "_" + (j+1);
                    //tb_name.Text = oReader["SchipNaam"].ToString();
                    createDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl
                        ("<div class='form-group'><div class='clearfix' ></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'></div><div class='col-md-3'> " + lstText[j] +
                         ": <input type='text' id='" + tb_name.ID + "' runat='server'/></div></div></div>"));
                    tb_names.Add(tb_name);
                } 

                i++;
            }
```

also if you will use for loop here you can reduce Lines of code.